# Changing NavigationItem title

Tags: swift, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to change the title in `Product` but somehow the `navigationItem` is different. How come the `navigationItem` in `Container` is different compared to the one in `Product`?

```
class VC1: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let controller = Container()
        let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)

        navigationController?.pushViewController(navigation, animated: true)
    }
}

class Container: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(navigationItem)
        navigationItem.title = "test"

        let controller = Product()

        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        self.addChildViewController(controller)

        view.addSubview(controller.view)
    }
}

class Product: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(navigationItem)
        navigationItem.title = "" // Doesn't remove the title
    }
}
```

Comment: what title you want in Container and what in Product ? Question is not clear

Comment: product is not pushed, instead it is added what you can do is set the title of the container to whatever you want when adding the product controller. Then you will be able to see the title.

Comment: @ShahzaibQureshi yea, I'm going to change the title in `Container`. Still I don't understand how `navigationItem` works.

Comment: try setting title from 'title="YOUR_TITLE"' instead of 'navigationItem.title="YOUT_TITLe"'

Comment: @HennyLee navigationItem shows up in a controller which is either a root controller of a UINavigationController or when it is pushed by a viewController using its navigationController. You are setting title on product but product is neither pushed nor it is the root of an UINavController therefore it's NavigationItem is nil and hence u can't set title on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just reading the documentation for `navigationItem`, and it says this:

> This is a unique instance of UINavigationItem created to represent the view controller when it is pushed onto a **navigation controller**.

However, in your case, the embedded VC is not a direct child of a navigation controller.

So, I tried the following code and it worked. The key part is I overrode `navigationItem` to return the parent's navigation item if there is a parent view controller.

```
override var navigationItem: UINavigationItem {
    if let parentItem = parent?.navigationItem {
        return parentItem
    } else {
        return super.navigationItem
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it works. But because I'm using many custom container views I found out I should use `navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem.title` instead.